# How to redirect to another page from ejs page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, ejs

my code is:

```
<%
var result = [];
if(result.length>0)
{
 //do nothing
}
else
{
 //redirect page to "/product-not-found"
 //window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); is not working
}
%>
```

Note: without passing res, req from node.js controller

when i add this code:

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

it's not working for me.
show me error:

```
window is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:215:37)
    at returnedFn (\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
    at tryHandleCache (\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at \controllers\productController.js:1274:8
    at \node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4733:16
    at \node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:263:16
    at \node_modules\mongoose\lib\aggregate.js:973:13
    at \node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:9)
```

Comment: it's not working @SiddharthDas i have already try it it's not js it's "product.ejs" page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hack you can try

1-Create a file called redirect.ejs with following code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=<%= url %>">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "google.com"
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        If you are not redirected automatically, <a href="<%= url %>">click here</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

2-Call this file as partial in your code like this

```
<%
var result = [];
if(result.length>0)
{
 //do nothing
}
else
{
%>
<%- include('redirect.ejs')%>// redirect to
 <%
}%>
```

Let me know if it works for you

Comment: it's show me error:
partial is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12), <anonymous>:219:7)
    at returnedFn (\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
    at tryHandleCache (\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
    at View.render (\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)

Comment: Pleased to help @NiravSutariya

Answer (score 0):

Until now, I didn't find a way to redirect from ejs page to another page, **IF** you are using data from the variabile that you should use in that ejs page.

So my solution is to redirect from the server-side, instead from the client-side.
In the example below, there is a login page which, at successful login, renders the account page, and, at unsuccessful login, renders the login page again.

File: `node.js`

```
//Profile page
app.get('/account', function (req, res) {
    if(req.session.user){
        // user can access account page
        let sess = req.session;
        console.log(sess);

        res.render('account', {user: sess.user});
    }
    else{
        // user cannot access account page
        // -> display again the login page
        res.render('login');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party but I had this issue and this is how I solved it:

```
<% if (yourBoolean) { %>
  <script> document.location.href = '/your-redirect' </script>
<% } %>
```

Forcing a redirect via a script tag, **with** EJS, not a redirect **from** EJS.

Happy coding!